# User input file/directory

Tags: input, java-io

I am trying to create a program able to copy a file from one directory to another, but I need to ask the user to select the file, and input the directory. How do i do that?

This is what I have done so far:

```
import java.io.*;


public class FileCopy {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

      File file = new File(".");
      File copyfile = new File(".");

      BufferedReader reader;
      PrintWriter writer;
      String line;

      try{
          if (copyfile.createNewFile() || !copyfile.createNewFile()) {
              reader = new BufferedReader (new FileReader(file));
              writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(copyfile));
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) !=null){
                writer.println(line);
                }
            reader.close();
            writer.close();

            }
      }catch(IOException ioEx){
          System.err.println("I could not copy the file to a destination directory");

      }
    enter code here

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use command-line arguments for user to enter the file name and the destination directory. To do so write something like the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args.length == 0 || args.length > 2) {
        System.err.println("Invalid arguments, enter a file path and a destination directory.");
    }

    File file = new File(args[0]);
    if (!file.isFile()) {
        System.err.println("First argument must be a file.");
    }
    if (!new File(args[1]).isDirectory()) {
        System.err.println("Second argument must be a directory");
    }

    File copyfile = new File(args[1], file.getName());
    ...
```

Besides that, you don't have to create a new file with `copyfile.createNewFile()`, the **FileWriter**(**File** file) constructor does it for you. In addition, code like `if (copyfile.createNewFile() || !copyfile.createNewFile()) { ...` does not look good, because it gets inside the **if** statement either ways, you could just call `copyfile.createNewFile()`.